# Acess data image url when the data url is only obtain upon rendering

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

I would like to automatically get images saved as browser's data after the page renders, using their corresponding [data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

For example:

1. You can go to the webpage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truck
2. Using the WebInspector from Firefox pick the first thumbnail image on the right.
3. Now on the Inspector tab, right click over the img tag, go to Copy and press "Image Data-URL"
4. Open a new tab, paste and enter to see the image from the data URL.

Notice that the data URL is not available on the page source. On the website I want to scrape, the images are rendered after passing through a php script. The server returns a 404 response if the images try to be accessed directly with the src tag attribute.

I believe it should be possible to list the data URLs of the images rendered by the website and download them, however I was unable to find a way to do it.

I normally scrape using selenium webdriver with Firefox coded in python, but any solution would be welcome.

Comment: Do u definitely wanna use selenium? Or is it ok if the solution uses BeautifulSoup? BeautifulSoup is better for such use-cases. But if u definitely wanna use selenium, then I will give u the solution in selenium.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work out a solution using chrome webdriver with CORS disabled as with Firefox I could not find a cli argument to disable it.

The solution executes some javascript to redraw the image on a new canvas element and then use toDataURL method to get the data url. To save the image I convert the base64 data to binary data and save it as png.

This apparently solved the issue in my use case.

**Code to get first truck image**

```py
from binascii import a2b_base64
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-site-isolation-trials")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truck")

img = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]"
                                   "/div[5]/div[1]/div[4]/div"
                                   "/a/img")
img_base64 = driver.execute_script(
    """
    const img = arguments[0];

    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    data_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    return data_url
    """, 
    img)

binary_data = a2b_base64(img_base64.split(',')[1])
with open('image.png', 'wb') as save_img:
    save_img.write(binary_data)
```

Also, I found that the data url that you get with the procedure described in my question, was generated by the Firefox web inspector on request, so it should not be possible to get a list of data urls (that are not within the page source) as I first thought.

Answer (score 0):

`BeautifulSoup` is the best library to use for such problem statements. When u wanna retrieve data from any website, u can blindly use `BeautifulSoup` as it is faster than `selenium`. `BeautifulSoup` just takes around 10 seconds to complete this task, whereas `selenium` would approximately take 15-20 seconds to complete the same task, so it is better to use `BeautifulSoup`. Here is how u do it using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import time 

st = time.time()

src = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truck').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'html.parser')

divs = soup.find_all('div',class_ = "thumbinner")

count = 1 

for x in divs:
    url = x.a.img['srcset']
    url = url.split('1.5x,')[-1]
    url = url.split('2x')[0]
    
    url = "https:" + url
    
    url = url.replace(" ","")
    
    path = f"D:\\Truck_Img_{count}.png"
    
    response = requests.get(url)

    file = open(path, "wb")

    file.write(response.content)

    file.close()
    
    count+=1 

print(f"Execution Time = {time.time()-st} seconds")
```

Output:

```
Execution Time = 9.65831208229065 seconds
```

29 Images. Here is the first image:

[image]

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately the difficulty is that I want to extract the images from the data URL that you get following the procedure I specified in the question. The Wikipedia was just a quick representation of the way I can get the data url by hand. The website I want to scrape is more complex with javascript rendering the parts where the images appear, that is why i use selenium. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: Additionally, as I specified in the answer, images cannot be retrieved from the src attribute directly, giving a 404 response status.

Comment: Okay...But then, this is an easier way to achieve the same output right? How much ever complex that website is, u can easily get the image urls using this method. Could u provide the link of that complex website that u r trying to scrape?

Comment: Yes. I am familiar with requests and BeautifulSoup. The images cannot acessed by the image urls directly. The image url goes to a php script that after failing to find some metadata, jumps to a catch exception that gives a 404 response. The reason I abstain from using the original website is that the difficulty comes from the fact that the website tries to protect the scraping of the images.